# Is there a boto 3 (aws sdk for python) API for getting the actual memory used by a lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am looking for an (boto3) API of aws lambda or aws cloud watch, which can tell me the max memory actually used by a lambda function on execution?

I know on every execution the lambda function prints the result which has 'max memory used' but I need an API for it

Answer (score 1):

We have no API to get that information directly. But you can get `MemoryUsedInMB` from Cloudwatch metrics.

At Cloudwatch metrics, find `All > Lambda > By Function Name` then you can see used memory in `Invocations`

Cloudwatch Lambda Metric => https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg//monitoring-functions-metrics.html

How to get metrics data => https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.get_metric_data

Comment: So the namespace will be ' Invocations' and metric name will be 'MemoryUsedInMB' ?
Also what will be the dimensions? @TuanVA

Comment: Metric name is invocations, dimensions is  all columns in metric

Comment: @TuanVo idk how are you saying that invocation metric will provide me MemoryUsedInMb. Also, i tried the API. This is the sample response - {'MetricDataResults':[{'Id':'sdfnklwedsd','Label':'Invocations','Timestamps':[datetime.datetime(2021,10,13,7,5,tzinfo=tzlocal()),datetime.datetime(2021,10,13,7,0,tzinfo=tzlocal())],'Values':[1.0,1.0],'StatusCode':'Complete'}],'Messages':[]}

Answer (score 0):

You can get that info using `get_log_events` e.g.

```
import boto3
logs_client = boto3.client('logs', region_name='us-east-2')
logGroupName='/aws/lambda/My_Function',
logStreamName='2022/07/09/[$LATEST]3aevb813776865536a146697b7379d5',

response = logs_client.get_log_events(
    logGroupName=logGroupName,
    logStreamName=logStreamName,
    limit=123,
)
```

`response` will have all the memory and duration info that you normally see in the console.

I hardcoded logGroupName and logStreamName but you can also just get them using `describe_log_streams` Example below only gets the latest log stream.

```
stream_response = logs_client.describe_log_streams(
            logGroupName = "/aws/lambda/My_Function", 
            orderBy='LastEventTime',                 
            descending=True,
            limit=1                                  
            )
print(stream_response)
```